# ReactJS wraps each letter of text node in a separate span. Why?

Tags: reactjs

I have one react component, which renders part of it's state like this:

```
<span className="filter-name">{ selectedText }</span>
```

But instead of one `<span>` with text, I get the following. Why?

`selectedText` is generated like this:

```
let selectedText = this.state.selected.map ( ( id ) => 
  this.locationsById[ id ].formalname ).join ( ", " ).
  trunc (this.maxTitleLength );
```

`locationsById` is array of objects. `formalname` is a string property there. `trunc` is implemented like this:

```
"use strict";
String.prototype.trunc = function( n, useWordBoundary ) {
    var tooLong = this.length > n,
        s_ = tooLong ? this.substr ( 0, n - 1 ) : this;
    s_ = useWordBoundary && tooLong ? s_.substr ( 0, s_.lastIndexOf ( " " ) ) : s_;
    return tooLong ? s_ + "…" : s_;
};
```

The result generated by React looks like this:

```
<span class="filter-name" data-reactid=".5.0.0">
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:0">Р</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:1">о</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:2">с</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:3">с</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:4">и</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:5">я</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:6">,</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:7"> </span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:8">М</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:9">о</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:a">с</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:b">к</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:c">о</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:d">в</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:e">с</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:f">к</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:g">а</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.0:h">я</span>
<span data-reactid=".5.0.0.1"> </span>
```

Before `trunc()` selectedText is dumped to console as `Россия` without any type reference. After `trunc()` it becomes

```
String 0: "Р"1: "о"2: "с"3: "с"4: "и"5: "я"length: 6__proto__: String[[PrimitiveValue]]: "Россия"
```

Comment: How is `selectedText` generated?  Just a string?

Comment: @DavinTryon Updated question with details. Thanks.

Comment: What does `selectedText` equal *before/after* the call to `trunc`?

Comment: @DavinTryon The result after trunc is posted at the bottom of the question. And it is somewhat confusing. It is a console.log() result from Chrome and it strangely tells, that it is a string, but composed of different characters. This is what bothers me. I don't understand what it means. Do you?

Comment: I admit, that is some strange output.  That is why I'm interested in what `selectectText` is after the `.join(", ")`, but before the `trunc`.

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I think that placing `trunc` on the `String.prototype` is causing the issue. :)  I'd have a hunt around and debug it out.  Because instead of setting `this` you are returning a value etc.

Comment: @DavinTryon Updated answer with results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: don't modify String.prototype! Bad things will and have happened.

Somehow you've ended up with a String object, like `new String('foo')`.

```
> typeof new String('foo')
'object'
> Object.keys(new String('foo'))
[ '0', '1', '2' ]
```

It's going away, but when you give React an object as a child, it'll interpret the keys as the `key`, so these are the same:

```
<div>{{foo: <span>bar</span>}}</div>
<div><span key="foo">bar</span></div>
```

When you give React text as a child, it wraps it in a span. So it sees an object with keys '0', '1', '2', ... and string values, so it renders them each as a span with the numeric keys.

---

I'm not sure why you have a String object, but doing `String(that)` will give you a normal string.

```
<span className="filter-name">{ String(selectedText) }</span>
```

---

And to reiterate: don't modify native prototypes, including String.prototype, Array.prototype, Object.prototype, etc!

Comment: I think the root cause is setting `_s` to `this` inside the `String.prototype.trunc`.

Comment: Why shouldn't I modify prototypes? All polyfills does that. It is convenient enough. Is there any downsides?

Comment: @DavinTryon Changing `this` to `String(this)` there solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny, polyfills are well thought out, and implement a well thought out and *standard* specification. Adding things to native prototypes is right after "don't eval" and "don't use with(){}" on the list of things to not ever do in JS.

Comment: You can google "don't modfy prototypes javascript" for more information, but it'd be hard to find someone justifying it. Even the people who did it originally, like mootools, have stopped doing it.